# Where does the Nilamata Purana sanction consumption of alcohol?

Tags: puranas, dharma-shastras

According to *Bodhayana Dharma Sutra* [1.1.2.4](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe14/sbe1435.htm#fr_745):

> 4. Now (the customs peculiar) to the north are, to deal in wool, to drink rum, to sell animals that have teeth in the upper and in the
>      lower jaws, to follow the trade of arms, to go to sea.

And the footnote for that Sutra says:

> The first two customs mentioned still prevail in the north, especially
>   in Kasmîr, where Brâhmanas commonly deal in wool and woollen cloth.
>   **Spirituous liquor is not now drunk openly, but its use is sanctioned
>   in the Kasmîrian Nîlamata-purâna.** Many Brâhmanical families in the
>   north, especially in the North-western Provinces, subsist by enlisting
>   as soldiers in the British and native armies.

Where does the Kashmiri Nilamata Purana sanction consumption of alcohol?

Also, the footnote for Sutra 5:

> A similar argument is given by the Kasmîrians for the lawfulness of
>   the consumption of meat, which they justify by a desaguna or 'virtue
>   of their country.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Nilamata Purana](https://archive.org/details/NilamataPuranaVedKumariGhai/page/n135) describes some rituals for [Hemantha and Sisira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ritu_(Indian_season)#North,_South_and_West_Indian_calendars) (November to February) Seasons for people of Kashmira. It  says wine can be drunk by those who are given to drinking on days of snowfall (translated by Ved Kumari Ghai)

> विशेषवच्च भोक्तव्यं भोजनं च यथेच्छकम् । 
>  नवो मद्यस्तु पातव्यो
> मद्यपैः पतिते हिमे ॥४८१॥
>
> viśeṣavacca bhoktavyaṃ bhojanaṃ ca yathecchakam । 
> navo madyastu pātavyo madyapaiḥ patite hime ॥481॥
>
> 481.On snow-fall, new wine should be drunk by those who are given to drinking. Special meals should be taken according to one's desire.

Comment: Thanks. Does this permit Brahmins to drink too, or just non-Brahmins?

Comment: @Ikshvaku Previous verses and next verses just say "they" or "one" which refers to People of Kashmir.

Comment: Ok, and what's the Sanskrit word translated to wine?

Comment: @Ikshvaku Madya. "navo madyastu pātavyo madyapaiḥ patite hime".. Nava = new ; madya = sprituous liquor ; astu = must be or should be  (be it); Paatavya = drunk ; madyapaih = those who drink; patite = fallen; hime = snow. Monnier William Dictionary says madya is "any intoxicating drink, vinous or spiritous liquor, wine"

Comment: Wine consumption may have been recommended to counteract intense cold in Kashmir in winter months Nov to Feb. Shariramadyam khalu Dharmasadhanam

Comment: @Narasimham Yes. Even i think the same. Also, some smritis suggest Non-Vegetarian food to  people of some places if Vegetarian food is not available in those places. So, you even see Brahmins eating Non-vegetarian food in some places of India.